# How to select a range in Listbox in code

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

If listbox has more than 1 selected items, how can I make selected all of items from min. selected index to max. selected index? For example;

listbox has `{c#, wpf, mssql, xaml, vs2013, tfs}`
if I select wpf and vs2013, I want to select mssql and xaml, too, in SelectionChanged() event.

Is it possible?

Edit: I take them to a list. How can I select range of them?

```
List <string> l = new List<string>();
if (listBoxGridColumns.SelectedItems.Count > 1)
    foreach (var item in listBoxGridColumns.SelectedItems)
    {
        l.Add(item.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: yes it is possible - what have *you* tried?

Comment: Have a look at ".SelectedItems"

Comment: I edited my question by what I tried. How can make select the range?

Comment: You want to select them visually based on a list you have or you need a list of the visually selected items?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SetSelected` method and specify the index of the items. In your case 2 and 3:

```
listBoxGridColumns.SetSelected(2, True);
listBoxGridColumns.SetSelected(3, True);
```

Since you ask for a range use this which will start at 2, and go to 3:

```
Enumerable.Range(2, 2)
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(index => listBoxGridColumns.SetSelected(index, True));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take the indices, get the smallest and the biggest and then set SelectedIndices to a list of int containing the indices from smallest to biggest.

```
List <int> indices = new List<int>();
if (listBoxGridColumns.SelectedIndices.Count > 1)
{
    foreach (int index in listBoxGridColumns.SelectedItems)
    {
        indices.Add(index);
    }
    indices.Sort();
    int smallest = indices.First();
    int biggest = indices.Last();
    for(int i = smallest; i <= biggest; i++)
    {
        listBoxGridColumns.SetSelected(i, True);
    }
}
```